# Extracting ERA5 daily temperature and precipitation for different points using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, climate

I'm struggling at finding a way to extract daily average temperatures and total precipitations for different points (an imported table as FeatureCollection), throughout a selected period of time (few years). At the moment, I am trying 2 options:

1. https://code.earthengine.google.com/dce98ed8676655aa41b8ad5f820f6eae
2. https://code.earthengine.google.com/de3052ead7a94c8a1b498da8b45f67e1

In the first one i get what i want but I need to change the structure of the outcome, since there are as many columns as the number of days analysed. What I want to obtain is a table with columns for the date, the sector ("settore"), the avrg temperature and the total precipitation.
Which is what i get in the secondo code, more or less, except that for each day I get the same tempertature and precipitation values, probably an overwriting problem.

I also tried to use only the ReduceRegions function on the selected dataset:

```
   var startDate = ee.Date('2014-10-01');
   var endDate = ee.Date('2014-10-10');

   var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
                                   .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                                   .select('temperature_2m');

   var reducedTemp = ee.FeatureCollection(dataset.map(function(img){
       return img.reduceRegions({
              collection: tos,
              reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
              scale: 30,
              crs: 'EPSG:4326'});
        }));
```

The problem here is that I get 24 data (per sector) for a single day and I'm not capable to reduce them to a single record per day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your two links code, I got an asset error so, I assumed only one arbitrary point in Italy (13.797235003125458, 41.65261836389952) for testing my code. It calculates for this point 'total_precipitation_hourly' as sum and 'temperature_2m' as mean for 24 hours each day. Values were corrected for expressing them in its respective units (mm for total precipitation and ºC for temperature). I mapped Image collection with individual functions for precipitation and temperature but they can be combined in only one. These functions produce for your date range (9 days) a list of 9 distinct dates and a list of paired values of precipitation and temperature for exporting them to Google Drive. Complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f1a051b4948980c96dd494c5b4463b4e) looks as follows:

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([13.797235003125458, 41.65261836389952]);

Map.addLayer(pt);
Map.centerObject(pt);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY");

var startDate = ee.Date('2014-10-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2014-10-10');
var diff = endDate.difference(startDate, 'day');

var precD = dataset.select('total_precipitation_hourly')
                  .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

var list_precD = precD.toList(dataset.size());

var tempD = dataset.select('temperature_2m')
                  .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

var list_tempD = tempD.toList(dataset.size());

var getPrecipitation = function(image) {

  var value_precipit = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), pt)
    .get('total_precipitation_hourly');
  
  var precipit_mm = ee.Number(value_precipit)
    .multiply(ee.Number(1000)); //original values are in meters

  var time = ee.Image(image).get('system:time_start');

  return precipit_mm;
};

var getTemperature = function(image) {

  var value_temp = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), pt)
    .get('temperature_2m');
  
  var temp = ee.Number(value_temp)
    .subtract(ee.Number(273.15)); //original values are in kelvin

  var time = ee.Image(image).get('system:time_start');

  // Return the time (in milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970) as a Date

  return temp;
};

var precipit_list = list_precD.map(getPrecipitation);

print("precipitation list", precipit_list);

var temp_list = list_tempD.map(getTemperature);

print("temperature list", temp_list);

var allDates = ee.List(precD.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  }).distinct();

var len = precipit_list.size();

var list = ee.List.sequence(0, len.subtract(1), 24);

//print(list);

var sum_precipit_list = list.map(function(ele){

  var start = ee.Number(ele).int(); 
  var end = ee.Number(ele).add(24).int(); 

  var new_list = ee.List([]);
  var element = ee.List(precipit_list.slice(start, end)).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());

  new_list = new_list.add(element);

  return new_list;

}).flatten();

var mean_temp_list = list.map(function(ele){

  var start = ee.Number(ele).int(); 
  var end = ee.Number(ele).add(24).int(); 

  var new_list = ee.List([]);
  var element = ee.List(temp_list.slice(start, end)).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());

  new_list = new_list.add(element);

  return new_list;

}).flatten();

//print(mean_temp_list);

var paired = sum_precipit_list.zip(mean_temp_list);

paired = allDatesSimple.zip(paired);

print (paired);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(paired.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list
  var geom = pt;
  return ee.Feature(geom, {
    'date': ee.String(el.get(0)),
    'values':ee.List(el.get(1))
  });
}));

//print(myFeatures);

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"hourly", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"hourly_data",  //file name
"CSV");
```

After running it in GEE code editor, my [csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10nGJzcnric-kX9PG3G9rKUD4Ds_5GGPO/view?usp=sharing) can be perfectly edited for producing corresponding stats. After edition, it looks as follows (dates, total precipitation and mean temperature daily; respectively):

```
2014-10-01,0.151218777034501,14.4043162027995
2014-10-02,9.27646323742692,13.3050126393636
2014-10-03,1.24336779106216,12.6744043986003
2014-10-04,0.531125068732763,12.1380198160808
2014-10-05,0.270527601173853,12.5899838765462
2014-10-06,0.627899169899138,12.472039159139
2014-10-07,0.014889240162575,13.0912865956625
2014-10-08,0.000860646668599,13.8759221394857
2014-10-09,0.00085234631797,14.7941274007162
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is huge! It works perfectly fine, though, my asset is a collection of points. To extend the iteration over my asset should I use reduceRegions instead of reduce Region?

Comment: If you want a result for each point you should have a Feature Collection of them and to map each feature with a function.

Comment: I'll try, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the ImageCollection before doing your call to `reduceRegions()`. This will leave you with only 1 outcome per sector:

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2014-10-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2014-10-10');

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
                               .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                               .select('temperature_2m')
                               .mean();

var reducedTemp = dataset.reduceRegions({
  collection: tos,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326'
});
```

Then you can also do the same with precipitation but instead reduce the Image Collection and the Regions with `.sum()`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried that but it is not what I need since I want to have one value per sector per each day of the selected period. Reducing the dataset by the mean I only get one value for the entire period.